# Is there a trivial way to get the 2's complement of an std::bitset<N>

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitset

I was using `std::bitset<N>` in my program and needed to find the least significant set bit and did the trivial calculation as below :

```
int num = 5;
int res = num & (-num);
```

After which the least significant bit of `num` is set in `res` and rest all are `0`'s. This works as `-5` is represented in 2's complement notation.

But I found `std::bitset<N>` doesn't have any operator overload for unary `operator -` which would have given me the 2's complement for the underlying bits. Is there a trivial way to implement the 2's complement with `std::bitset<N>` ? I could always use `operator ~` to flip the bits and loop over them doing the sum and carry starting from LSB to MSB, but I was looking for a solution which would avoid that.

Comment: Certainly there are a lot of **non-trivial** ways of doing almost anything!

Comment: I noticed I should have used __trivial__ :-p Will edit the title.

Comment: Note that looping over the flipped bitset is most-likely as fast as simply looping over the original bitset in order to find the least significant bit (which I find the trivial solution in this case ;))

Comment: @Zeta Of-course, why didn't I think of it !! That's what I'll end up doing perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bitset` doesn't provide any complement methods. Since you would have to calculate the complement yourself with `operator~` and an additional loop, simply skip `operator~()` and search for the LSB directly:

```
template <int N>
size_t least_significant_bit(const std::bitset<N> &bt){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bt.size(); ++i){
        if(bt.test(i))
            return i;
    }
}
```

I guess it can't get more trivial than that ;).

Note that the result of `least_significant_bit` isn't specified if there's no bit at all. One could return `N` or change the loop in order to test `bt.test(N)` which would throw an exception, but after all it doesn't really make sense to look for a LSB in a nulled bitset.

Further note, you can use `std::bitset<N>::operator[]` instead of `std::bitset<N>::test` if you're not interested in boundary checks.

Comment: Sorry for the index mess, I was thinking in terms of [`to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string) (*"The resulting string contains N characters with the first character corresponds to the last (N-1th) bit and the last character corresponding to the first bit."*) instead of using simple bit logic >.<

Answer (score 1):

this should do it unless I am missing something

`std::bitset<N> twos_comp = std::bitset<N>((~input).to_ulong() + 1);`

Comment: This however only works for up to N = 64, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

a quite convenient method for doing two's complement is finding the least significant 0 in your bitset, setting that to 1 and setting all less significant bits to 0.

pseudocode: (assuming that set[0] is the least significant bit, if not, turn it around)

```
int i = 0;
while (i < set.length && set[i])
  {
     set[i] = 0;
     ++i;
  }

if (i < set.length)
  set[i] = 1;
```

Comment: There is no `operator -` or `operator +`, hence the inconvenience :-)

Comment: don't forget to handle the all ones case